# Web-Sockets to bind to http server or to start new

Tags: websocket, socket.io, serversocket, tclientsocket

I've been looking for a detailed answer to this question for some time now, whether to start a new websocket on the server domain, or attach a receiver to the http server that is already running, for example Express with Node.js.

I have tried countless times in both directions: internal server client to internal-server host connection, or server to external client like the Javascript browser, but no success so far. Anyone have a working example or a link with a working example? I have tried countless times, even on the same server between two files as the example below.

The setup I have here from [here](https://github.com/websockets/ws), the server.js file

```
const WebSocketServer = require('ws');
const wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 8080 });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  ws.on('message', function message(data) {
    console.log('received: %s', data);
  });

  ws.send('something');
});
```

Tnen there is the browser.js file

```
import WebSocket from 'ws';

const ws = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8080/');

ws.on('open', function open() {
  ws.send('something');
});

ws.on('message', function message(data) {
  console.log('received: %s', data);
});
```

What the problem is, I really can't figure it out